# iPhone MFMailComposeViewController cuts off text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmailcomposer

I'm using `MFMailComposeViewController` inside my application and I've noticed that part of the message has been cut off. Right now it's only trimming the "Sent from my iPhone" text, but should users remove this, I don't want any of the message trimmed back.

Here's a screen cap of what I'm talking about:

[image]

To keep my app description as simple as possible, I'm launching the `controller` from a `TabController` and it covers the whole screen as a `modalView`.

Comment: How are you opening the MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: Hmm, originally I had it set to open via the UITabBarController, but I switched it to the navigation controller (I have them nested) and now it works. Thanks for suggesting a double check.

Comment: You need to use this code to make it work:
`MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
//Setting up the Subject, recipients, and message body.
[mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"email@email.com",nil]];
[mail setSubject:@"Subject of Email"];
[mail setMessageBody:@"Message of email" isHTML:NO];
//Present the mail view controller
[self presentModalViewController:mail animated:YES];`

You have to add it to self and not to a view

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found that it was a header tag at the beginning of the html which seemed to be throwing the entire system spacing off. NO IDEA WHY

Limit yourself to `<div><p>` using inline styles to get the look you want and it should correct the issue

Or even more simply, put a non breaking spacer `&nbsp;` before the `<h1> or <h2> etc`