# mfmailcomposer cuts end of html email

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mfmailcomposer

I've created an in app email feature to ask a question that opens the mfmailcomposer and fills it with html content.  Unfortunately it seems to cut off the final line of the email so it appears as the image below.

[image: Here's an example]

I have set the mfmailcomposer to self, followed every tutorial I can find, the only reference to fix it has said the following:

1. make sure your mfmailcomposer is set to self ie. [self presentModalViewController:email animated:YES];
2. make sure it's embedded within a navigation controller

Neither solution works.

I have found that if the email contents is short enough that the entire email fits on screen the problem doesn't appear but if you continue typing to push the contents off the edge it reappears.

Any ideas on a solution? Or is this an Apple xcode "design feature"?

Comment: I've found this issue only seems to affect the view if the body is in HTML format (unfortunately a necessity for my project).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone MFMailComposeViewController cuts off text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163652/iphone-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-cuts-off-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue, it seems to be a bug, that's the only explanation I can reach.

If the start of your content is a header (`<h1>, <h2>, <h3>, etc`) tag (even if it is within a HTML and BODY tag) it creates this issue.

If you want to start your email body with a header tag then the simplest way of fixing it is to add a non breaking spacer before the header tag, it seems to completely resolve the issue.

Comment: Tony, just as a hint for your future use of StackOverflow: it's not a forum, and answers to a question are not posts in a thread. So unless something is an answer intended to close your question (and you are perfectly allowed to provide your own answers to your own questions!), either edit a question, an existing answer or post it as a comment.

Comment: Now to comment your answer. You probably should limit use of HTML to very, very basic HTML anyway. Anything not supported by the email composer itself should probably be considered an unsupported use, anyway; links, bolding and italic is safe due to font size not changing, but I wouldn't use tables, images, etc.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to close this thread on Friday but you are unable to answer your own question without waiting 24 hours.

Headers are available in the mail composer and function normally, as I stated this simply seems to be a bug.I had already limited my html in this case to follow the incredibly limited stylings available in HTML emails.

Comment: What is the problem with Tony's question/answer?? Having the same problem I found both very useful. Thanks Tony!

Comment: For those who might have to go search for a non breaking spacer: &nbsp

This worked for me by adding: @"<html>&nbsp<body>" - so the non break infront of the main body paragraph. Else just play around with its positioning and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a framework bug. Does it occur on different versions of iOS? Try it with both older and newer versions of the operating system and on other devices.

Are you 100% certain that the view is not actually larger than its container view? Explore the view hierarchy. Perhaps in plaintext Apple adds some spacing, so it doesn't seem like the content is out of bounds of the parent view, although it is.

How do scroll indicators behave? Are they also clipped?

Are you presenting the message composer in a fullscreen view? If you're trying to present it in a view that is controlled by a sub-controller of the tab view controller,  that might cause the composer view controller to be confused.

For what it's worth, I've just tested my code which generates HTML content, and there is no clipping. This is on iOS 4.2.1 on iPhone 3G, but I don't remember seeing the problem on iOS 5.1 either.

---

Some tips.

While debugging, don't forget: view controllers are actually just managing views that still have their own hierarchies. To clarify, view controllers may have a hierarchy, but their hierarchy does not necessarily correspond to view hierarchy. (Although it should in the near total majority of cases.) Same thing with views themselves: they have their hierarchy, but they still just control the underlying Core Animation layers, which have their own hierarchy.

You can always access view hierarchy itself and explore it in greater detail through debugging facilities you come up with yourself. What you shouldn't be doing is meddling too much in parts of the view hierarchy that's supposed to be managed by the view controllers, just like you shouldn't mess too much with the parts of the layer hierarchy that's supposed to be managed by the views.